# A bug in Winedt?

Tags: winedt, auto-completion

Reproducing:

1. Put caret in point A
2. Right-click on a citation from bibliography branch in tree panel and choose insert
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> to undo the insertion.
4. Put caret in point B
5. Right-click on a citation from bibliography branch in tree panel and choose insert
6. The citation key is placed in point A, while it is supposed to be placed in point B.

Is this a bug? or how it works?
I also realized that if you double-click on the citation instead of right-click and insert, it works properly.

PS: I am using Winedt 8.1 in Win7!

Comment: This is not the place to make bug-reports, they should be rather be addressed to the developer(s) of WinEdt: http://www.winedt.com/support.html

Comment: True, but as it is clear in my question, I wasn't sure if this a bug or not!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug and will be fixed in WinEdt 8.2.

In the meantime, you can get things working properly in this way.

1. Open `Tree.ini` from the "Options Interface".
2. Do the following global replacement with Regular Expressions on:

   Search for:   `<\(0@{ }\)MACRO="GlobalReturn;\(1*\)GlobalMark;"`

   Replace with: `<\0MACRO="GlobalMark(1);GlobalReturn;\1"`
3. Press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to apply the changes.
4. Open `Gather.ini` and repeat the above steps.

Now it will work as expected.

---

**IMPORTANT**

These changes have to be rolled back before you install WinEdt 8.2 and use the "Upgrade" function, otherwise the Upgrade process will fail.

To roll things back, this is the replacement you have to do in `Tree.ini` and `Gather.ini` (with Regular Expressions on):

Search for:   `<\(0@{ }\)MACRO="GlobalMark(1);GlobalReturn;\(1*\)"`

Replace with: `<\0MACRO="GlobalReturn;\1GlobalMark;"`

Comment: @user114781 You're welcome. Remember to undo the changes before upgrading to v8.2.

Comment: sure, do you know when 8.2 will be released? and what's new?

Comment: @user114781 End of April - Beginning of May. Bug fixes, hystory of backups, support for high resolution monitors.

Comment: @karlkoeller has this bug been fixed successfully? If yes, please write a little node and close as off-topic. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi As I wrote in my answer, the bug had to be solved in version 8.2 and it has been solved in that WinEdt version. I don't see the need to close the question as off-topic, however...

Comment: @karlkoeller thanks for the update. Yes, we can leave it open. Sure. I just thought, it tidies the page up as this issue should not effect any other user in future and it is directly clear that the bug is gone. But with your last comment, we are clear as well. Everthing fine.